# SSL/TLS process problems, maybe TLS Record layer issue

Tags: ssl, https, proxy

I'm developing a server handling SSL. It can process the SSL request from a browser. Usually the request begins like this:

0001 0110 0000 0011 0000 0001

Meaning: (0001 0110) is 22, a handshake Record. 0000 0011 is 3, 0000 0001 is 1, it means SSL version 3.1

The server works fine with the request from browser.

> [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) is an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between their machine and the Internet.

But when I turn on Charles SSL proxying, as Charles is a man-in-the-middle, although the request is started by a browser, the server actually got the request from Charles. The request begins like this:

1000 0000 0110 1110 0000 0001

Then I don't know how to process this at all. To me it's not following any SSL protocol. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use an existing SSL library? This is a large project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason is a little bit complex. Generally because I'm using Lisp. The only library I can find (CL+SSL) has a memory leak issue in my case. I already finished the ssl process anyway and it works fine for browser request. Just I don't know why not Charles Proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. It's a 'version 2.0 CLIENT-HELLO message'. 'Note that this message MUST be sent directly on the wire, not wrapped as a TLS record.'

The detail is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-E.2